# insertar multiples registros al seleccionarlos con checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, insert

Buen dia

Estoy realizando el siguiente inserto a mi DB,todo bien me inserta el dato de todos los que selecciono mediante el check box si seleccion 3 los 3 registros los inserta el problema es que deberia registrarmelo con diferente numero de empleado pero me toma el valor del ultimo numero de empleado no me toma en cuenta los demas al principio solo realizaba un registro de los 3 seleccionados lo solucione y despues no guardaba el numero de empleado y lo arregle pero ahora solo guarda un solo numero de empleado

Me podrian orientar para saber que es lo que tengo mal redactado en mi codigo o que parte fue la que hice mal

El valor del numero de empleado lo tomo de un input que tengo oculto el cual me da el mismo valor que la columna codigo_persona

Codigo Formulario :

```html
<tr>
  <td>Certificacion:</td>
  <!-- Campo de texto combinado con lista de opciones -->
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="certi" list="items" autocomplete="off" />
    <!-- Lista de opciones -->
    <datalist id="items">
   <option value="Montacargas">Montacargas</option>
    <option value="Navaja">Navaja</option>
    <option value="Uso de pallet jack">Uso de pallet jack</option>
    <option value="Electroestatica">Electroestatica</option>
    <option value="Quimicos">Quimicos</option>
   </datalist>
  </td>

  <td>Fecha de certificacion</td>
  <td>
    <input type="date" name="fechaCer" id="" />
  </td>
  <td>Fecha de vencimiento</td>

  <td>
    <input type="date" name="fechaVen" id="" />
  </td>
</tr>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<table id="employee_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th hidden>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Numero Reloj</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Puesto</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Departamento</th>
      <th>Turno</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <?php
                                            
       $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
                                            
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                                                
       $id=$row['id_emp'];
                                                
    ?>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_emp']; ?>" /></td>
        <td hidden><input type="text" name="nr" value="<?php echo $row['codigo_persona']; ?>" /></td>
        <td align=center>
          <?= $row['codigo_persona'] ?>
        </td>
        <td align=center>
          <?= $row['Nombre'] ?>
        </td>
        <td align=center>
          <?= $row['Puesto'] ?>
        </td>
        <td align=center>
          <?= $row['Categoria'] ?>
        </td>
        <td align=center>
          <?= $row['Departamento'] ?>
        </td>
        <td align=center>
          <?= $row['Turno'] ?>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <?php
         }
      ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar" />
```

Codigo post:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


$id=$_POST['id'];
$count = count($id); 
$noreloj=$_POST['nr'];
$cer=$_POST['certi'];
$fech=$_POST['fechaCer'];
$ven=$_POST['fechaVen'];


for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $llenar=  strlen($cer) * strlen($fech) * strlen($ven) * strlen($noreloj);

    if($llenar >0){
        require("validate.php");
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO certificaciones (Certificacion,Fecha_Cert,Fecha_Ven,empleado_id) VALUES ('$cer','$fech','$ven','$noreloj')")or die ("Error:No se ingresaron los datos:");
        mysqli_close($link);
             ?>
        <script>
        alert("Se ha registrado exitosamente");
        window.location.href='./../work/certifications.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    
    }
    
    else{
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Faltan datos por llenar");
        window.location.href='./../work/certifications.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}

}


?>
```

Imagen table

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como lo tienes puesto, estás repitiendo el `name="nr"` en cada ciclo y cuando lanzas el formulario tan solo te coge uno de ellos.

Una posible solución pasaria por renonbrar ese name a algo así:

```
<td hidden><input type="text" name="nr_<?php echo $row['id_emp']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['codigo_persona']; ?>" /></td>
```

de este modo, si el id_emp vale, por ejemplo, 15, entonces el name de ese empleado seria **nr_15**.

Luego, en el PHP, para recoger ese dato, lo puedes hacer así:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $ids=$_POST['id'];
  $count = count($ids); 
  $cer=$_POST['certi'];
  $fech=$_POST['fechaCer'];
  $ven=$_POST['fechaVen'];
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $noreloj=$_POST['nr_'.$id];
    $llenar=  strlen($cer) * strlen($fech) * strlen($ven) * strlen($noreloj);
    etc...
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos es renombrar la variable **$id** de antes por **$ids** y luego recorrerla con un **foreach()** en lugar del **for** para que nos vaya dando el **id** correcto en cada ciclo y así podamos descubrir el código de empleado al hacer la asignación `$noreloj=$_POST['nr_'.$id];`

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Sabes que ya lo ejecute como me dices pero no me realiza el insert de nada solo se pasa directo al else de faltan datos por rellenar

else{
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Faltan datos por llenar");
        window.location.href='./../work/certifications.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }

Comment: Añadi una imagen de la tabla y el check box y el valor de no reloj que es el que quiero almacenar en mi tabla certificaciones

Comment: A ver, quizás no me expliqué del todo bien, pero donde pones esto: `$noreloj=$_POST['nr'];` debes modificarlo por esto:  `$noreloj=$_POST['nr_'.$id];`.  Es decir, los dos a la vez no deben coexistir por si acaso el que se ejecuta es el que no toca.

Comment: Si yo se

$id=$_POST['id'];
$count = count($id); 
**negrita** `$noreloj=$_POST['nr_'.$id];`
$cer=$_POST['certi'];
$fech=$_POST['fechaCer'];
$ven=$_POST['fechaVen'];

Asi lo deje desde que me dijiste

Comment: Vale, ya veo que ocurre... el $_POST['id'] es un array y no hace bien lo del `nr_$id' despues porque no lo estas recorriendo bien.  A ver como lo arreglo...

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, mira si ahora te va bien

Comment: Me funciono de maravilla muchas gracias por la ayuda